# LibGDX 3D how to stop objects from rendering if between those objects and camera already some object

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

So i have a voxel game like minecraft made using LibGDX and i have 65k blocks on my screen and all of them renders together but I want only blocks that I can see to render, and blocks that I can't directly see - don't render

I've already tried to use frustum but it only decreased rendering blocks from 65k to about 30k

Comment: If your blocks are opaque, you should just drawn them and let the GPU take care of fragment culling. That’s what the GPU is optimized for and what the CPU would be really slow at. About 20 years ago, games used the BSP technique for culling what couldn’t be seen, but that was for enclosed areas and you would have to code that on its own since it’s definitely not built into libGDX.

Comment: Before you think about culling, you should probably stop rendering full quads and pre-calculate which faces are "outside" faces. Faces between two cubes will never be visible and can be left away. That alone should get you down to a reasonable number of faces to render. If you don't already do this: Batch together all faces into a single buffer and render them with one draw call instead of one call per face/cube.

Comment: Since you got blocks, you can write a compute shader that generates the vertex buffer only for those blocks that you need to render. Would that be faster, that is the question.

Comment: The way that games like Minecraft work is they don't even put the blocked faces in the vertex buffer. There are just way too many faces to render them all. But most faces are blocked.